# ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 30, saw 3

Tags: pandas

I was trying to read this text file using pandas.read_csv() but I get this error " ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 30, saw 3". I know this is a silly question. I'm sort of a newbie.
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv("source-document00001.txt",sep=".")

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the erroring rows

```
data = pd.read_csv("source-document00001.txt",sep=".", error_bad_lines=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, @oli5679 it works. Since I'm working on an NLP project. Most of the context would be missing and there is a chance that I would get inaccurate predictions.

Comment: @Arjun_dev good luck. It's hard to suggest alternatives without access to the file.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct, but on the documentation it says, "Deprecated since version 1.3.0: The on_bad_lines parameter should be used instead to specify behavior upon encountering a bad line instead."

```
data = pd.read_csv('source-document00001.txt',sep='.',on_bad_lines='skip')
```

Comment: What's considered a "bad line?"